# getting Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateError does not exist when using custom validation extend()

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating custom validation for two fields, url and attachment fields. I am trying to validate that only one field is to be required from both but when user fill both fields he can get error to fill only anyone field.

For this, in my AppServiceProvider.php i did:

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
      /**
       * Register any application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function register()
      {
        //
      }

      /**
       * Bootstrap any application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function boot()
      {  

        Validator::extend('empty_if', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $fields = $validator->getData(); //data passed to your validator

            foreach($parameters as $param) {
                $excludeValue = array_get($fields, $param, false);
                // dd($excludeValue);

                if($excludeValue) { //if exclude value is present validation not passed
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return true;
        });

        Validator::replacer('empty_if', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
            $replace = [$attribute, $parameters[0]];
            $message = "The field :attribute cannot be filled if :other is also filled";
            return  str_replace([':attribute', ':other'], $replace, $message);
        });
      }
    }
```

and in my controller:

```php
    public function createFile(Request $request){
          $this->validate($request,[
              'url' => 'empty_if:attachment|url|URL|string',
              'attachment' => 'empty_if:url|attachment',
              'attachment.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,doc,docx,zip,rar,pdf,rtf,xlsx,xls,txt,csv|max:1999',
              'client' => 'required|string',
              'projectTask' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
```

when submitting form I am getting this error:

```php
    message:    Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateAttachment does not exist.
    exception:  BadMethodCallException
```

kindly tell me is there any mistake in the logic in extend(). Where I am doing mistake so I am getting this error.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
'attachment' => 'empty_if:url|attachment',
```

There it says to validate the `attachment` field with the `empty_if:url` rule and the (non-existing) `attachment` rule.

Comment: so can you explain how to resolve this for validating one field is required when both are empty and only fill one field is required when both are filled ?

Comment: Take a look at closure based conditional rules: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: I have already check and it is not suitable for my requirement. I want user to fill only one field when both fields are being present

Comment: Ok then just remove `|attachment` from your `attachment` rules as I wrote in my answer. Everything after a pipe `|` will be interpreted as a new rule. And the rule `attachment` doesn't exist as your error message says.